# Which HTTP status code should I send when redirecting users to a specific country?

Tags: http, http-headers, http-status-code-301, http-status-codes

If I had a website with the following different locations;

www.site.com/uk/
www.site.com/us/
www.site.com/ca/

When "User X" (could even be Google) first navigates to www.site.com I want to check their IP and guess that they should be redirected to the /uk/ version (or whatever).

The user can still opt to change their country at any time (ala GoDaddy.com) but when they initially land and are redirected, what should I send as the HTTP status code?

I first thought a 301 but technically it isn't a permanent redirect because "User Y" might be from Canada and therefore www.site.com should go to www.site.com/ca/

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `302` is appropriate. To me `301` seems to be too strict, because the originating URL which was sending the Redirect still exists. Also from SEO point of view crawlers should still visit the old "root"-URL.

As you mentioned Canada, I have a real world example which is doing it this way. Have a look at Kijiji Canada, when you choose a region (e.g. http://toronto.kijiji.ca) afterwards going to http://www.kijiji.ca you will be redirected to the selected region with `302`.

Comment: The proper way to handle this is to also add a `Vary:`header. You could use `Vary: Accept-language` if you base your redirection decision on that header; but as you say you base your decision on the client IP, you should use `Vary: *` (as explicitly suggested by [the RFC](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-7.1.4)). Ithink that with a suitable `Vary:` header even a 301 might be appropriate; but as this just states that the exactly same redirect will happen for every request that also has the same unspecified extra headers and IP and stuff, there is no longer a difference to a 302